# Syntax error rendering JavaScript as text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm writing some documentation in React and getting a syntax error when I try to write JavaScript within the render function. I'm not sure if this is a security issue with a workaround or if it's actually a parser issue:

```
export default class Docs extends Component {
  render = () =>
    <div>
      <h1>Example:</h1>
      <div className={styles['code-block']}>
        `
        import Calendar from './Calendar'

        const config = {
          api_key: 1234,
          calendars: [{ name: 'demo', url: 'example@group.calendar.google.com' }]
        }
        `
      </div>
    </div>
 }
```

I've tried both with the back tick and without but still get the same syntax error:

```
Module build failed: Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected }
```

referencing the colon just after `api_key`. Is there a way to do this, or am I better off taking a different approach.

Comment: try wrapping it with `{``}`, right now the parser is confused at what should be escaped to actual JS and what is a string in JSX

Comment: @rlemon do I have to worry about the parser parsing it as JS?

Comment: no, that's what the template literal is doing. making it a string. but without telling the parser to treat _that_ like JS, it's just arbitrary backticks. just don't include any `${}` wrapped stuff in there. or escape it within the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    export default class Docs extends Component {
  render = () =>
    <div>
      <h1>Example:</h1>
      <div className={styles['code-block']}>
        {`
        import Calendar from './Calendar'

        const config = {
          api_key: 1234,
          calendars: [{ name: 'demo', url: 'example@group.calendar.google.com' }]
        }
        `}
      </div>
    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to wrap it in brackets:

```
{`
  import Calendar from './Calendar'

  const config = {
    api_key: 1234,
    calendars: [{ name: 'demo', url: 'example@group.calendar.google.com' }]
  }
`}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiline code should be wrapped in parentheses and using non other than html markup, you'll need to use curly bracket to parse them:

```
export default class Docs extends Component {
  render = () => ( {/* 1 */}
    <div>
      <h1>Example:</h1>
      <div className={styles['code-block']}>
       { {/* 2 */}
        `
        import Calendar from './Calendar'

        const config = {
          api_key: 1234,
          calendars: [{ name: 'demo', url: 'example@group.calendar.google.com' }]
        }
        `
       }
      </div>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

**{/* 1 */}**

Instead of using parentheses you may also use curly brace and use return statement like:

```
  render = () => {
    return ( <div> {/* optional parentheses */}
     Optional, since it is in same line as return line
    </div>)
  }
```

Or, like:

```
  render = () => {
    return (  {/* required parentheses */}
      <div>
       Required, since it is in different line from return line
    </div>
   )
  }
```

**it** meant to be starting html markup like `<div>` in the preceding example.

**{/* 2 */}**

Using curly brace in the preceding example will result as it is since everything is wrapped in template literal or inside a string. Note that if you use variable like `${some_var}` inside the template literal, then it will result its value not as it is. If you want in some case, then just escape the curly brace like `$\{some_var}`

Answer (score 1):

the `backquote` `` (`) `` operator is not text or string, it is an operator, like a `JavaScript` function. A `JavaScript` function must be inside `{}` when used inside `JSX`. so you should write like below:

```
export default class Docs extends Component {
  render = () =>
    <div>
      <h1>Example:</h1>
      <div className={styles['code-block']}>
        {`
        import Calendar from './Calendar'

        const config = {
          api_key: 1234,
          calendars: [{ name: 'demo', url: 'example@group.calendar.google.com' }]
        }
        `}
      </div>
    </div>
 }
```